# Upside Down Word Puzzle

Tags: word, wordplay

Think of a 4-letter word for something seen in the winter (lowercase). Turn it upside down, and you'll name a device used with this thing. **What is it?**

(credit to  Hugh Stoll of Harrisonburg, Va.)

I am getting really frustrated that I can't figure this out!!!!

Answer (score 15):

The answer is

> "**wool**", which people wear in winter.
>  When inverted, the word "wool" becomes "**loom**", a device that can be used for [weaving wool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YNw6PkH9lzA).

Answer (score 9):

Is it

> plow/mold?

Explanation

> On a snow plow there's something called a moldboard, which is the big curved part. From a few web searches I couldn't find any reference to a moldboard being called simply a mold, but there are cases where it's broken into two words; I could see some people calling it a mold. A moldboard is also made using a mold, so maybe that's what it's referring to?